# Why my final function doesn't integrate to "1" when "normalized" in R?

Tags: r, function, statistics, bayesian, integral

I have a coding question about `integrate()`. It arises from a few steps:

**First**, I have an Initial function called `Like`. **Second**, I get the integral of `Like` and call the outcome `norm.cons`. **Third**, I divide the `Like` by `norm.cons` and call the outcome `Like.2`. **Finally**, I get the integral of `Like.2`. (***All R code is provided below.***)

## Question:

By definition, the answer of my final step above should be "1". But why instead I get the following answer? `4.573253e-12`

## Here is my R code:

```
Like = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = seq(1, 30), 2), prod) # Initial function

norm.cons = integrate(Like, -Inf, Inf)[[1]] # Integral of Initial Function

Like.2 = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = seq(1, 30), 2), prod) / norm.cons # Deviding the initial function by its Integral

integrate(Like.2, -Inf, Inf)[[1]] # HERE Why Integral is not "1" ?
```

Comment: norm.cons is 0.

Comment: @Christoph, please see my edited question?

Comment: Your function does not make sense. Have a look at `x <- c(-100:100);
plot(x, Like(x))` and `norm.cons`.

Comment: @Christoph. is this also show bad: `curve(Like, from = 14, to = 17, col = 'red', lwd = 3)`?

Comment: Your "maximum" is at 1e-143! Perhaps you should explain what you want to achieve and then refomulate the question.

Comment: @Christoph, Yes, this function is supposed to have that. I guess I need to get the log of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `norm.cons` variable is 0, which means anything you put in `Like.2` results in `NaN` (division by 0). Try, for example,

```
Like.2(3) # results in NaN
```

The reason `norm.cons` is 0 is that it is 0 at *almost* all values except those around 200-300, and numerical integration is too imprecise to find the region where it is not 0. For example, try:

```
Like(220) # 3.471218e-244
Like(300) # 2.661608e-296

# outside of that region:
Like(200) # 0
Like(320) # 0
```

To fix this, set more reasonable bounds around both of your integrations (it won't hurt the calculation since almost none of your function's mass occurs outside that region). For example:

```
Like = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = c(250, 265, 259), 2), prod) # Initial function

norm.cons = integrate(Like, 220, 300)[[1]] # Integral of Initial Function

Like.2 = function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = c(250, 265, 259), 2), prod) / norm.cons

integrate(Like.2, 100, 500)[[1]]
```

This results in `0.9999309`, very close to your expected value of 1. The difference is due to the imprecision of numerical integration, as well as arithmetic underflow (some values aren't 0 but are too small for R to represent). If you play around with the bounds of your integrals a bit you can get it even closer to 1.